# Can we change FLS for required field?

Tags: profile, security, field-level-security

I am aware of following:

> ProfileFieldLevelSecurity
>
> ProfileFieldLevelSecurity represents the field level security for users assigned to a profile. In API version 30.0 and later, permissions for required fields can’t be retrieved or deployed.
>
> *Taken from [Metadata API - Profile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm)*

I just want to know, if there is any way to change FLS for required fields by any other way?

Answer (score 4):

You can only change the FLS for required fields if they are required only by the page layout. In this case you can remove the field from the layout, and it won't be required anymore.

If the requirement is on field level, then there's nothing you can do. The field should be on the layout and will **always** be required.

Field-Level Security - Salesforce Security Guide: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/admin_fls.htm

Difference between making field required in page layout vs while field creation : https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hoc7AAA

Comment: thanks for updates! I understand your point logically.  But can you please provide  any documentation link? It will be very helpful..

Comment: I've added some links to references to the original post.